# Transfer how to deliver message to Gateway?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/tcp-client-server-multiplex
I saw this exmaple. So, I was changed architecture.

- send model
  [image]
- receive model
  [image]
  And I have a question.
  I don't understand transfer's role in send model.
  I understand Aggregator delivery message to Transfer.
  But, I don't understand How to deliver message to gateway.
  How to deliver?

That is my spring integration config.

It is Send app setting,

```
  <!-- telegram bean -->
  <bean id="byteArrayRawSerializer" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayRawSerializer">
    <property name="maxMessageSize" value="2000"/>
  </bean>  
  <bean id="myCorrelationStrategy" class="com.test.util.MyCorrelationStrategy"/>
  <!-- online connection factory -->
  <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="server" type="server" port="20001" single-use="false" lookup-host="false" so-timeout="60000" serializer="byteArrayRawSerializer" deserializer="byteArrayRawSerializer" />
  <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client" type="client" host="localhost" port="10001" single-use="false" so-timeout="60000" serializer="byteArrayRawSerializer" deserializer="byteArrayRawSerializer" />

  <!--  Send -->
  <int:gateway id="sendGateway" 
        service-interface="com.test.MySendGateway"
        default-reply-timeout="20000"
        default-request-channel="sendChannel"/>

  <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="sendChannel" />

  <int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="sendAdapter" order="2" channel="sendChannel" connection-factory="client" /> 

  <int:bridge input-channel="batchSendChannel" output-channel="toSendAggregator" order="1"/> 

  <int:channel id="toSendAggregator" datatype="byte[]"/>

  <int:aggregator input-channel="toSendAggregator"
        output-channel="toSendTransformer"
        expire-groups-upon-completion="true"
        correlation-strategy="myCorrelationStrategy"
        correlation-strategy-method="getCorrelationKey"
        release-strategy-expression="size() == 2" />

  <int:transformer input-channel="toSendTransformer"  expression="payload.get(1)"/>

  <int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="sendReplyAdapter" channel="toSendAggregator" connection-factory="client" />  

  <!--  Receive -->  
  <int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="inboundAdapter" channel="batchInboundChannel" connection-factory="batchReceiveServer" />  
  <int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="outboundAdapter" channel="batchOutboundChannel" connection-factory="batchReceiveServer"/>

  <int:channel id="batchInboundChannel" />

  <int:channel id="batchOutboundChannel"/>

  <int:service-activator id="myReceiveServiceActivator" method="receive" input-channel="batchInboundChannel">
    <bean class="com.test.endpoint.MyReceiveServiceActivator" />
  </int:service-activator>
```

And, It is Delivery app setting(center of picture),

```
  <!-- Bean load -->
  <bean id="byteArrayRawSerializer" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayRawSerializer">
    <property name="maxMessageSize" value="2000"/>
  </bean>  

  <!-- Connection factory -->
  <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="server" type="server" port="30001" using-nio="true" single-use="false" lookup-host="false" so-timeout="10000" serializer="byteArrayRawSerializer"  deserializer="byteArrayRawSerializer" />  
  <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client" type="client" host="${RemoteTarget.ip}" port="${RemoteTarget.port}" using-nio="true" single-use="false" so-timeout="10000" serializer="byteArrayRawSerializer"  deserializer="byteArrayRawSerializer" />

  <!-- Connection factory -->
  <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="inboundServer" type="server" port="10001" using-nio="true"  single-use="false" lookup-host="false" so-timeout="${server.outbound.connectionTimeout}" serializer="byteArrayRawSerializer"  deserializer="byteArrayRawSerializer" />  
  <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="inboardClient" type="client" host="localhost" port="20001" using-nio="true" single-use="false" so-timeout="10000" serializer="byteArrayRawSerializer"  deserializer="byteArrayRawSerializer" />

  <int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="receiveAdapter" channel="receiveChannel" connection-factory="server" auto-startup="true"/>
  <int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="sendReplyAdapter" channel="sendReplyChannel" connection-factory="client" auto-startup="true"/>

  <int:channel id="receiveChannel"/>
  <int:channel id="sendReplyChannel"/>

  <int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="receiveAdapter.inboard" channel="receiveChannel" connection-factory="inboundServer" />
  <int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="sendReplyAdapter.inboard" channel="sendReplyChannel" connection-factory="inboardClient" />

  <int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="sendAdapter" channel="sendChannel" connection-factory="client" />  
  <int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="receiveReplyAdapter" channel="receiveReplyChannel" connection-factory="server" />

  <int:channel id="sendChannel" />

  <int:channel id="receiveReplyChannel"/>

  <int:router id="outRouter" input-channel="toRouter" method="route" auto-startup="true">
      <bean class="com.test.endpoint.MyRouter"/>
  </int:router>   

  <int:channel id="toRouter"/>

  <int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="sendAdapter.inboard" channel="toRouter" connection-factory="inboundServer" auto-startup="true"/>
  <int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="receiveReplyAdapter.inboard" channel="toRouter" connection-factory="inboardClient" auto-startup="true"/>
```

But, When I call gw.send(msg), it is not work,
(exactly, message stop at the delivery machine's 'sendAdapter.inboard' until timeout and router get this message....

Answer (score 1):

I an not sure what is `transfer` in your ar3chitecture either.

According the sample you show, we have:

```
gateway -> outbound-channel-adapter
        |-> aggregator

inbound-channel-adapter->aggregator->transformer
```

Where `gateway` sends its request to both TCP Outbound Channel Adapter and Aggregator, just because of `<publish-subscribe-channel id="input" />`.

As we know `gateway` is a request/reply component. When it sends requests, it waits for reply, because of the contract:

```
public interface SimpleGateway {

    String send(String text);

}
```

In this case the Gateway add `TemporaryReplyChannel` as a `replyChannel` header to wait for reply.

The reply is produced when we don't specify the `output-channel` on the last downstream flow consumer.

In our case it is exactly the `<transformer>` after `<aggregator>`:

```
<transformer input-channel="toTransformer.client"
    expression="payload.get(1)"/> <!-- The response is always second -->
```

I think that is a trick what you are looking for. It is called `replyChannel` header in the Consumer logic.

Comment: I don't know your architecture, but if you follow with that `multiplex` sample you really have to use the same `publish-subscribe-channel` as for `tcp:outbound-channel-adapter`, as well as for the `aggregator`. But according to your code for the last one you use fully different channel - `batchSendChannel`. Please, be careful with the code, I'm not sure that we should do the work for you...

Comment: Sorry.. batchSendChannel is just typing error. I will change to exact configuration.

Comment: So, to help you more I need some minimal config which demonstrate the problem. I mean something with what we can play locally. Plus you can switch on DEBUG for the `org.springframework.integration` category and trace your messages journey in logs. E.g. determine if the request is really sent to the aggregator, if you are receiving reply via `tcp-inbound-channel-adapter`. Maybe the problem in your `myCorrelationStrategy` and you can't determine the `correlationKey` properly for the reply. At a glance you're good. Although you might send `String` to the gateway, but your channel expects `byte[]`